# What is the meaning of "rocks my world"?

Tags: phrases

From [a discussion on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17/what-is-using-this-network-socket):

> lsof rocks my world! grep on IPv4 as well to find various IP based things

The `lsof` is a command you can ignore, but how about the *rocks my world*? What's the meaning of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple definition lookup (from *Urban Dictionary*):

> [rocks my world](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=rocks%20my%20world) - *When someone/something makes life so much better...*

Indeed IPv4 addresses do (according to the abstract of a [technical paper](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/multimedia/documents/technical-publication/beyond-counting-new-perspectives-on-the-active-ipv4-address-space.pdf)):

> ...we report on techniques and analyses that enable us to capture Internet-wide activity at **individual IP address-level granularity** by relying on server logs of a large commercial content delivery network (CDN) that serves close to
>   **3 trillion HTTP requests on a daily basis**. [*emphasis added*]

Comment: I don't think IPv4 rocks anyone's world these days.